# Can this be strongly typed?

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union

I'm trying to implement a sort of pseudo pattern matching in Typescript using their support for discriminated unions, making use of a match function along with an object representing the branches of the match expression.

Here's the scenario I'd like to be able to use:

```
type Shape = 
    | { kind: 'Circle', radius: number }
    | { kind: 'Rectangle', height: number, width: number }

function printShape(s: Shape) {
    return document.write(
        match(s, {
        'Circle': c => `Circle(${c.radius})`,
        'Rectangle': r => `Rectangle(${r.width} x ${r.height})`
    }));
}
```

My current attempt at the definition of the match function looks like this:

```
function match<T extends { kind: V }, V extends string, R>(
    x: T, branches: { [P in T['kind']]: (arg: T & { 'kind': P }) => R }) {

    return branches[x.kind](x);
}
```

This is close but unfortunately doesn't quite work; while I have successfully got the compiler to complain about completeness for the given matches, the arguments to the branching functions are not well-typed: the arguments `c` and `r` have type `any`.

I'm fine with having `kind` as a hardcoded discriminator, but I generally don't understand in Typescript how to filter possibilities out of a generic type union. For example, I distilled my exercise down to trying to write the following:

```
type Where<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> = ???
```

I have my type constraints correct in that I get the correct validation about my types and literals from the compiler when I write:

```
type Circle = Where<Shape, 'kind', 'Circle'>
```

but I don't understand what I can write on the right hand side of that type expression to return:

```
{ kind: 'Circle', radius: number }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract a specific type from a union you can use the `Extract` conditional type. This will extract all members of the union that are a subclass of the second parameter. So your where type would look like this:

```
type Where<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> = Extract<T, Record<K, V>>
type C = Where<Shape, 'kind', 'Circle'> //{ kind: 'Circle', radius: number }
```

You can get full types for the function if you use a function that returns a function. The first call sets `T` and the second call can use the type info to fully type the parameters:

```
type Shape =
  | { kind: 'Circle', radius: number }
  | { kind: 'Rectangle', height: number, width: number }

function printShape(s: Shape) {
  var r = match(s)({
    'Circle': c => `Circle(${c.radius})`,
    'Rectangle': r => `Rectangle(${r.width} x ${r.height})`
  }) // r is string
  return document.write(r);
}


function match<T extends { kind: V }, V extends string>(x: T) {
  return function <R>(branches: { [P in T['kind']]: (arg: Extract<T, { 'kind': P }>) => R }) {

    return branches[x.kind](x as any);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you! Well done on the speed of the answer too.